# Disable user/group create/delete as part of sbt native packager rpm install

Tags: scala, rpm, sbt-native-packager

I currently have both user and group defined as part of my sbt file:

```
daemonUser in Linux := "appuser"

daemonGroup in Linux := "appgroup"
```

This tries to create the user and, worse, on uninstall removes the user. The user is created by our chef scripts so i don't need the rpm to create it and by deleting it, subsequent install will re-create it with the wrong uid/gid. Is there a way to define the daemonUser, but defeat the auto-create/delete?

In the same vein, is there a way to defeat the auto-enable of the service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the RPM scriptlets by putting your versions in `src/rpm/scriptlets` as described here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/GettingStartedServers/OverrdingTemplates.html

Answer (score 0):

You could override default templates as described here http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/GettingStartedApplications/OverridingTemplates.html.

Comment: The templates i'd have to override are the rpm pre/post install/uninstall ones, but i can't quite figure out where'd they go locally, or if those templates can be overridden